# how to configure PostgreSQL database for the ubuntu (windows store) app?

Tags: windows, postgresql, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am currently using the Ubuntu App that I downloaded from the Windows AppStore and I wanted to know how to configure PostgreSQL database for Ubuntu App.
your help would be deeply appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you want install Postgres on ubuntu you can find your answer in link below.

https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/